# Issues in spying a windows application utilizing BluePrism

Tags: windows, robotics, blueprism

I am facing the below issue while working on BluePrism, the issue relates to spying elements from a windows application called "Cashier", the application is written in VB, I provided the .exe file for it and the application launched properly, however, I can't properly spy the individual rows in the table shown in the attached picture. I can only spy the box as a whole, and no information is retrieved.
[image: Windows Application Spying issue]

Comment: Have you tried using the Application Navigator or [UI Automation Navigator](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-6-7/en-us/uia-navigator-form.html?tocpath=Interface%7CStudio%7CObject%20studio%7CApplication%20modeller%7C_____1) to spy the table?

Comment: yes, I did with no luck. @esqew

Answer (score -1):

possible the application spawns the elements in a new process? perhaps check the task manager once and make sure another process hasn't spawned to show the results in?